# Jettpack Compose not showing Ads banner (AdView)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the code below to display AdMob Ads, but unfortunately it's not showing anything. Please let me know if I have missed something

```
@Composable
fun AdvertView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            factory = { context ->
                AdView(context).apply {
                    adSize = AdSize.BANNER
                    adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            },
            update = {
                it.apply {
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if any log errors are being displayed in your logcat?

Comment: I see the folowin error in the Logcat
"GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms"

Comment: Same issue with info: I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3, using test ad.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problelm.. What worked for me was making sure I had internet connection and waiting a bit for the banner ad to load when I run my code..

Also  Since Admob 21.0.0, you would get the following error:

Val cannot be reassigned

So, instead of

```
adSize = AdSize.BANNER
```

use

```
setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Admob Banner Ad.
Here is my working code with the test Id

***Gradle*** Dependency I'm Using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
```

**Banner Composable Code**

```
@Composable
fun BannerAds(
    modifier: Modifier,
    adListener: AdListener? = null
) {

    val deviceCurrentWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
    val padding = 1
    var i by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var containerWidth by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(60.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.White)
            .onSizeChanged {
                containerWidth = it.width
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Text(text = "Showing Ad")
        AndroidView(factory = {
            AdView(it)
        }, modifier = modifier, update = {
            if (it.adSize == null)
                it.setAdSize(
                    AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
                        context,
                        deviceCurrentWidth - padding * 2
                    )
                )
            try {
                it.adUnitId = adUnitId //Can only be set once
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (adListener != null)
                it.adListener = adListener

            it.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        })

    }
}
```

**Use it** like this whenever you need it.

```
 BannerAds(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
```

Sometimes even after doing all things, the ad does not load.
then add some extra stuff.

Add in ***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

Add Below code on ***MainActivity OnCreate method***

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

AdMob in Jetpack Compose (Banner and Interstitial) [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/YkoEe6YZvq0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31188049)